# Why `NSKeyedUnarchiver` is unable to decode for `Date`

Tags: ios, swift, persistence

Recently, I was dealing with persistence on iOS with `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.  But I got some problem.

Here is the code:

```swift
import Foundation

class Model {
    static let instance = Model()
    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let TestArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("t")

    static func getInstance() -> Model {
        return instance
    }
    var str = "String"
    var date = Date()

    func save() {
        let coder = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: false)
        coder.encode(str, forKey: ModelPropertyKey.str)
        coder.encode(date, forKey: ModelPropertyKey.date)
        do {
            try coder.encodedData.write(to: Model.TestArchiveURL)
        } catch {
            print("error write to file: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: Model.TestArchiveURL)
            let decoder = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: data)
            let strGot = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: ModelPropertyKey.str) as? String
            let dateGot = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: ModelPropertyKey.date) as? Date
            print("\(String(describing: strGot)) \(String(describing: dateGot))")
        } catch {
            print("Error read from file")
        }

    }
}
```

I encode data with `encode(:forKey:)` and gain persistence with `encodedData.write(to:)`.  Then I try to read the data from disk with `NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom:)` and `decodeObject(forKey:)`.  But this strategy works for `String` and fails for `Date`.  The `print` output:

```
Optional("String") nil
```

I wonder why this happened.

Comment: The date acts like a complex type here but you can always save the timestamp `Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the object type you are trying to decode and since you are decoding `Date` object you need to understand that `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` will bridge your `Date` Swift object to `NSDate` Objective-C object for compatibility between swift and obj-c because `NSKeyedArchiver` uses `NSCoding` and `Date` does not conform to `NSCoding`

To do that change your decoding to be like this

```swift
let dateGot = decoder.decodeObject(of: NSDate.self, forKey: ModelPropertyKey.date)! as Date
```

However I would suggest that you use the swift `Codable` protocol with `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` they have a really good `dateDecodingStrategy` which allows for specifying your custom date formatter when encoding and decoding and they also support decoding `Date` objects directly without bridging to obj-c `NSDate` that's good when your trying to send your object as a json payload or decoding it from a network call

here is an example

```swift
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .full
formatter.timeStyle = .short
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

let data = try? encoder.encode(Date())

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
let newDate = try? decoder.decode(Date.self, from: data!)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code works! But I got another question: When I save a whole `Date` object in a standalone url with `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:)`and use `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(_:) as? Date` to unarchive it, it works.  Why?

Comment: I guess doing that makes the `NSKeyedArchiver ` do the bridging automatically since there is only one object in that data archive, I am not sure.